# Code to know where visitors come from with error simplexml_load_string():

Tags: php, wordpress, parsing

i'm receiving this errors because of a php code

```
 PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 42: parser error : Premature end of data in tag meta line 4 in /home/*****/public_html/wp-config.php on line 19 


 PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_string():  in /home/*****/public_html/wp-config.php on line 19
 PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_string(): ^ in /home/*****/public_html/wp-config.php on line 19


 PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 37: parser error : StartTag: invalid element name in /home/*****/public_html/wp-config.php on line 19

PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 40: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: script line 34 and body in /home/*****/public_html/wp-config.php on line 19


 PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 42: parser error : Premature end of data in tag head line 3 in /home/*****/public_html/wp-config.php on line 19
```

This is the code:

```
<?php
define( 'WP_CACHE', true ); // Added by WP Rocket

define('WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE', 'minor');// This setting is required to make sure that WordPress updates can be properly managed in WordPress Toolkit. Remove this line if this WordPress website is not managed by WordPress Toolkit anymore.
 // Added by WP Rocket

function convertXML($xml_content){
    if(is_object($xml_content)){
        foreach ($xml_content as $key => $value){
            $xml_content[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
    else {
        $xml_content = $xml;
    }
    return $xml_content;
}

$IP_ADDR = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$xml_get = file_get_contents("http://freegeoip.net/xml/$IP_ADDR");
$xml_content = simplexml_load_string($xml_get);
$xml_convert = convertXML($xml_content);
if($xml_convert['CountryCode'] != 'BR' or $xml_convert['CountryCode'] != 'US'){
    
    $block_cmd = "\r\n deny from $IP_ADDR \r\n";
    $include = 'testando.html';
    $open = fopen($include, 'a');
    fwrite($open,$block_cmd);
    fclose($open);
}else{
    
}

/** Enable W3 Total Cache Edge Mode */
define('W3TC_EDGE_MODE', true); // Added by W3 Total Cache



/**
 * The base configurations of the WordPress.
```

I tried modifying the line 19 ($IP_ADDR = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];) in several ways but the error keeps alive.. i don't know whats happening

This code is for to know where visitors of your website are coming from. I tried modifying the line 19 in several ways, also tried to add this function to the code that i saw in a topic

```
function sxe($url)
{   
    $xml = file_get_contents($url);
    foreach ($http_response_header as $header)
    {   
        if (preg_match('#^Content-Type: text/xml; charset=(.*)#i', $header, $m))
        {   
            switch (strtolower($m[1]))
            {   
                case 'utf-8':
                    // do nothing
                    break;

                case 'iso-8859-1':
                    $xml = utf8_encode($xml);
                    break;

                default:
                    $xml = iconv($m[1], 'utf-8', $xml);
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    return simplexml_load_string($xml);
}
```

but this didn't worked also.

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to parse HTML as XML. Can an HTML parser not be used?

Answer (score 0):

I would take a closer look at what you're actually being sent from freegeoip.net.

If it is indeed HTML you're getting back from freegeoip.net, but has the information you want, you could try

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($xml_get);
$xml_content = simplexml_import_dom($dom);
```